# I want to drag and drop .java files into a specific package in Eclipse to achieve the ideal hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse

#### Background and what we want to achieve

I am developing Java in Eclipse. I originally stored and managed .java files in packages, but in order to organize .java files, I moved .java files in packages to folders as shown in the following hierarchy.

However, as a result, the .java files are no longer executable. Probably the reason for this is because the .java files are stored in a folder, not in a package. I would like to move all .java folders into a package.

Ideally, I would like to create the following package hierarchy.

#### The hierarchy I would like to make

src {Java_basic (chapter1, chapter2)}{Java_Practice(chapter1, chapter2)}

#### Problems that are occurring / Question

However, when I drag and drop a specific file into a specific package, an error occurs. How can I achieve the above hierarchy with .java files stored in a package?

[image: screen image]

#### Version

Language: Java
Development environment: Eclipse
Version : 2022-12 (4.26.0)

After moving the .java file to a specific package, the first line in the file `package chapter10;` to `package Java_basic`, but the error message *"The declared package "chaoter10" does not match the expected package "Java_basic""* is displayed and the file cannot be executed.

Comment: Change the first line of every Java file you moved to the correct name for your "perfect" hierarchy. It must be identical. Also, you can't change the `src` folder without modifying the project properties. `src` isn't part of the package name. See [source folders](https://i.imgur.com/vd0LWFu.png) under Java Build Path under project properties.

Comment: Also note: packages _are_ folders. There's no distinction. Additionally, `.java` files are _never_ executable, they are only compilable into `.class` files which a jvm can run for you.

Comment: When you move files again, use Eclipse's refactor tool. It will move files, adjust package declarations, and even import statements of users of the moved classes.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
I changed the first line of Java files, and it solved problem.